# What does a fractional order of reaction mean for the mechanism?

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics, rate-equation

I'm doing a high school/sixth form college investigation of the kinetics between magnesium ribbon and hydrochloric acid. I have obtained a rate order was $1.5$ with reference to $[\ce{H+}]$ and hence the rate equation is

$$\mathrm{rate} = k[\ce{H+}]^{1.5}.\tag{1}$$

How does this fractional order correlate with the mechanism?

I remember my teacher once telling me that a fractional rate order just means that there is an intermediate stage and each step has its own rate order which contributes to the rate equation:

$$\ce{A ->[$x$] B ->[$y$] C}$$
$$x + y = n$$
$$\mathrm{rate} = k[\ce{A}]^n.\tag{2}$$

Is this right? Also, what would this mean for my rate-determining step? If the above is true, what would I choose as the RDS if they both contribute a different amount to the rate order?

Comment: $x + y = n$ certainly won't hold for all cases. For instance in this case all of the A could be quickly converted to B, but C forms very slowly.

Comment: A reaction mechanism is (generally) a very complicated thing which you can't hope to deduce from orders alone. One may say a fractional order indicates that the actual mechanism is "not simple" (that is, more complicated than _"all molecules simply meet and turn to products at once, just like the equation says"_). But then again, it is pretty much never simple.

Answer (score 13):

Here's an example.

Let's consider a reaction of the generic form:

$$\ce{3A -> 2C}$$

Now, let's say we have some knowledge that this reaction proceeds by the following two-step mechanism:

> Step one is fast and reversible.

$$\ce{A <=>[k_1][k_{-1}] 2B}$$

> Step 2 is slow and irreversible.

$$\ce{A + B ->[k_2] C}$$

The rate of the reaction (expressed as the change in concentration of the product per unit time) can be expressed in terms of the concentrations of A and B.

$$\mathrm{rate}=\dfrac{\Delta [\ce{C}]}{\Delta t}=k_2[\ce{A}][\ce{B}]$$

However, we would prefer to not use intermediates in our rate law. Since the first step is fast and reversible, we can use the law of mass action to create a relationship between the concentrations of A and B:

$$K_1=\dfrac{k_{1}}{k_{-1}}=\dfrac{[\ce{B}]^2}{[\ce{A}]}$$
$$[\ce{B}]^2=K_1[\ce{A}]$$
$$[\ce{B}]=\sqrt{K_1[\ce{A}]}$$

If we substitute into the  rate law:

$$\mathrm{rate}=\dfrac{\Delta [\ce{C}]}{\Delta t}=k_2[\ce{A}]\sqrt{K_1[\ce{A}]} =k_2 K_1^{1/2}[\ce{A}]^{3/2}$$

The term $k_2 K_1^{1/2} =\dfrac{k_2 k_1^{1/2}}{k_{-1}^{1/2}}$ becomes $k_{\mathrm{obs}}$, the observed rate constant of the overall reaction. The fractional order comes from the second step being rate-determining, but the first step being an equilibrium with stoichiometry that generates the fractional tern.

Comment: This is well explained, but it should be commented that the only real conclusion that can be drawn from a fractional order coefficient is that there are multiple steps involved in the reaction.  The actual orders are not explicitly informative.

Comment: So Can I claim for an elementary reaction, the order can never be fractional or negative ( if it involves no intermediates ) Also what does it mean to sy if the order with respect to an reactant is negative ?