# Negative or fractional order of reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, reaction-order

Let $\ce{A}$ be the reactant and $\ce{P}$ the product at the imaginary elementary reaction $\ce{A->P}$.
Could it possibly have a net total order of $-1?$

$$-\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{A}]}{\mathrm dt} = k[\ce{A}]^{-1} \tag{1}$$

Or even more, a reaction whose rate depends on the concentration of the product as it follows:

$$-\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{A}]}{\mathrm dt} = k[\ce{P}] \tag{2}$$

Is there any example of an actual reaction that behaves like that?

On the other hand, can we think about non-integer orders of reaction like $1.5$, $0.5$, $-0.5$, $2.368$, $\mathrm e$ or $\pi$ for instance? Any examples?

Comment: Orders of reaction are experimental parameters. So they cannot be predicted in advance. They can be 0, 1, 2 or 3. But a reaction may have no order at all, like the reaction H2 + Br2 -> 2 HBr, which rate is a complicated fraction containing the three concentrations. In principle, it is not absolutely impossible to have reactions with an order different from 0. 1, 2 and 3. But I must admit, I have never seen any such reaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia has you covered for both parts of the question in their article on Rate equation.

They give an example of a [negative order of reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_equation#Negative_order):

$$\ce{2 O3(g) -> 3 O2(g)}$$

Under certain conditions, this reaction is of -1 order in $[\ce{O2}]$. This covers your question about a reaction being dependent on the product concentration (equation 2 in OP's question) as well as having a negative order (equation 1 in OP's question).

They also give an example of a [fractional order of reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_equation#Fractional_order):

$$\ce{COCl2(g) -> CO(g) + Cl2(g)}$$

This has an order of 0.5 in chlorine.

##### Elementary or one-step reaction?

If the reaction is elementary, the reaction orders are equal to the the stoichiometric coefficients of the reactants. I'm not sure what is meant with a one-step reaction. For the examples given in this answer, there are radical intermediates in multi-step mechanisms ([What does a fractional order of reaction mean for the mechanism?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/49088/72973)) that explain the unusual kinetic features.

Comment: Ok, but about the question 1 I meant negative order for a product.

Comment: A starting point for searching for a negative order for the product would be the term "product inhibition". This is fairly common for enzyme-catalyzed reactions where the product, looking similar to a reactant, clogs up the active site: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_inhibition